# Como hago para depurar archivo PHP en netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

He estado intentando configurar el xdebug del php.ini pero resulta que en ese archivo no viene nada de xdebug, veo tutorial y en todos pone esa palabra y en mi archivo de configuracion no lo encuentro. Como puedo solucionarlo? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega esto a tu php.ini:

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9002
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\IIS\tmp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.3-7.1-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
```

La ddl la puedes bajar de la pagina de [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/download.php) y es muy importante que `remote_port` coincida con lo que esta configurado en la interfaz gráfica de netbeans. Las rutas y versiones dependen de tu instalación.

Comment: Muchas gracias, justo había hecho eso, pero aun así tampoco me funcionaba me faltaba el parámetro xdebug.remote_enable = on que no lo tenia puesto. De nuevo gracias.